# comprimir múltiples carpetas y cada una en un archivo zip con zipfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

estoy tratando de crear un script en python 3.8 para comprimir multiples carpetas. por ejemplo:

carpeta_1 > carpeta_1.zip
carpeta_2 > carpeta_2.zip

el tema es que no lo puedo lograr, este es mi codigo actual, que si bien no tira errores, no crea los archivos .zip.

```
# importing required modules 
from zipfile import ZipFile 
import os 

def get_all_file_paths(directory): 

    # initializing empty file paths list 
    file_paths = [] 

    # crawling through directory and subdirectories 
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory): 
        for filename in files: 
            # join the two strings in order to form the full filepath. 
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename) 
            file_paths.append(filepath) 

    # returning all file paths 
    return file_paths         

def main(): 
    # path to folder which needs to be zipped 
    directory = './python_files'

    # calling function to get all file paths in the directory 
    file_paths = get_all_file_paths(directory) 

    # printing the list of all files to be zipped 
    print('Following files will be zipped:') 
    for file_name in file_paths: 
        print(file_name) 

    # writing files to a zipfile 

        # writing each file one by one 
        for file in file_paths:

            with ZipFile(file,'w') as zip: 
                zip.write(file) 

    print('All files zipped successfully!')         


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

seria de mucho agrado que pudieran orientarme como poder realizar esto, ya que me es bastante grande la confusión tanto para trabajar con los for, y con la libreria os.

Saludos

Comment: Hola Samsara, ¿todas las carpetas están en el mismo directorio padre, al mismo nivel? O ay carpetas anidadas (sudirectorios)? Si es esto último, ¿Que pasa si una carpeta tiene dntro ficheros y carpetas?

Comment: e probado con subdirectorios y sin subdirectorios y no funciona en ningún caso.